# Python Re: How to match any string that has at least 1 letter?

Tags: python, python-re

I just want to match any string that has at least 1 letter. See example below. Thanks

```
import re

string1= "23  2021Sep Oct2021 Pte. 9K8 Ltd,"

Desired Outcome --> ['2021Sep' ,'Oct2021', 'Pte', '9K8', 'Ltd']
```

Comment: but you don't want the dot and the comma?

Comment: try `[\S]*[A-Za-z][\S]*`

Comment: @GhostOps, the OP wants at least one character. I am sure that the regular expression is wrong and complex. `[\S]` can be substituted into `\s` and `[A-Za-z]` does not hold for numbers.

Comment: @FaranAiki OP wrote "letter", not "character".

Comment: @MichaelButscher, yes, I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do without re like this:

```
[''.join(cc for cc in w if cc.isalnum()) for w in string1.split() if any(c.isalpha() for c in w)]
```

that outputs

```
['2021Sep', 'Oct2021', 'Pte', '9K8', 'Ltd']
```